# Customized workbench in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, workbench

I don't normally use eclipse, so please forgive my ignorance. Actually to analyze trace files generated by a simulator (I'm working with), the company that provides that simulator, also provides a Workbench and eclipse plugins for analyzing those trace files.

Now I'm a little bit confused here. In this context, what does a Workbench means? Is it some kind of a custom workbench. How do we install and use such workbenchs. I'm asking, because the company doesn't explain installing that workbench. Perhaps they assume that the user is already familiar with eclipse.

Moreover, what are the extensions of a workbench, so that I might search for them in the directory. Perhaps they have an example workbench to start with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A workbench is actually a perspective which is a composition of different views. The common way of installing plug-ins in eclipse is either using the marketplace or an update-site (Eclipse menu -> `Help` -> `Install New Software...`). They can also be installed from a local directory or on the "dirty way" by just copying them into the eclipse folder.
In which way does the the company provide the additional plug-ins?